# Как ускорить запись переменных?

Tags: python

Как ускорить запись переменных button ?

```
while True:
        pda.press('e')
        button_left = pga.locateOnScreen(path_left, confidence=0.8)
        if button_left is None:
            pga.keyDown('left')
        button_right = pga.locateOnScreen(path_right, confidence=0.8)
        if button_right is None:
            pga.keyDown('right')
        button_down = pga.locateOnScreen(path_down, confidence=0.8)
        if button_down is None:
            pga.keyDown('down')
        button_up = pga.locateOnScreen(path_up, confidence=0.8)
        if button_up is None:
            pga.keyDown('up')
```

Comment: Что значит «ускорить»? Какая скорость сейчас и какой скорости вы хотите добиться? Что такое `pga`?

Comment: @andreymal py game похоже

Comment: @andreymal Сейчас скорость записи  переменной 1,5 сек+- хотелось бы 0,5. pga это pyautogui